# Is there any way to add Interfaces to SObjects?

Tags: apex, oop

I have a problem where we have two SObjects with similar fields and we often convert one to the other. On top of that we have two classes that represent each of the SObjects as a DTO and another DTO class that unifies both those classes.

On those objects' fields we have to make calculations and the best thing would be to add an interface to the SObjects and the DTOs so that they can make those calculations independently without having to be converted to a class that contains all the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst your idea is great OOP, it's not possible in Salesforce. Instead, I'd recommend having one 'Domain' class for each SObject and having that use the Interface. Salesforce offers a [few trailhead modules](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_dsl/apex_patterns_dsl_learn_dl_principles) on the idea of a 'Domain' layer if you're unfamiliar, but the best examples and explanation can be found in the original author's book, [found here](https://www.packtpub.com/eu/programming/lightning-platform-enterprise-architecture-third-edition).

On a related note, if the SObject's really are that similar you might consider using [Record Types](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/customize-a-salesforce-object/create-record-types) instead of having two separate SObjects (apologies if you've already considered this).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll definitely read about it.
On another note, I also believe the best thing would've been to use one Custom Object since 90% of the fields are in common, too bad I didn't take part in the analysis stage

Comment: Ha - this sounds all too familiar. Best of luck in retrospectively convincing them.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to add behaviour to an SObject is to wrap it in an Apex class (e.g. your DTO). Do remember, however, that SObject (as [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)) has methods such as get and put that allow you to get and set field values based on field names (rather than field descriptors). This is good for when you do want to use a simple Map<String, String> to define how to correlate fields in one object type to fields in another, perhaps using a specific format of string obtained from a custom metadata type instance.

Your calculations could themselves be separate from the SObjects and simply use configuration that defines the field names for the fields involved in the calculations.

Another option, depending just what the calculations are, would be to embed the calculations in the SObjects as [formula fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_formuladef.htm&type=5). The downside - restrictions on just what you can do, limits on numbers of cross-object references and (if the same calculation applies to more than one object) having to effectively duplicate the expression.

Comment: We've considered all of this, but it all feels like the workaround of a workaround. The calculations are a bit too complex for standard formula fields, thanks anyway for the suggestion

Comment: Good. Basically SObjects are special and can't be added to. It isn't a workaround to a workaround, but rather the way you have to work with Salesforce.